# Schengen visa for my wife and kids

Tags: france, schengen-visas, applications, family

I am planning to visit Paris/France for 10 days. I have valid schengen business visa however my wife and kids have no schengen visa. Since they are going to apply for tourist visa do I need to mention my visa status while applying for their visa ?My wife is home maker and I will sponsor the trip on behalf of my family.

Comment: Others with better knowledge may answer but it seems to me that your family’s chance of receiving their visas depends on the fact that you are sponsoring them, will be travelling with them, and you already have your visa. Therefore you should provide your visa status in their applications. If having your family remain at home while you travelled was a factor in your own visa being issued there’s a possibility they may not be successful.

Answer (score 1):

My experience, you will likely need to mention the status of your visa when filing for your kids, but it is possible in principle to avoid that. Rules require that:

- Both parents file for visa together with kids.
- Both parents provide copy of their visa.
- One or both parents submit a note that they allow their kid to travel (this may vary per jurisdiction, in my experience it's somewhat PITA to make)

Otherwise there is no requirement - it is possible that you're sending your kids together with your wife and sponsor this travel without travelling yourself.

Please note that I have no idea whether you can legally enter EU on your visa or not.